# Java jsoup link extracting

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract the links within a given element in jsoup. Here what I have done but its not working:

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements element = doc.select("section.row");
        Element s = element.first();
        Elements se = s.getElementsByTag("article");


            for(Element link : se){
                System.out.println("link :" + link.select("href"));
            }
```

Here is the html:
[image]

The thing I am trying to do is get all the links withing the article classes. I thought that maybe first I must select the section class ="row", and then after that derive somehow the links from the article class but I could not make it work.

Comment: And what do you get as result?

Comment: the code above doest give any result, when I tried to print the element it shows me the same content as in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();      

    Elements section = doc.select("#main"); //select section with the id = main
    Elements allArtTags = section.select("article"); // select all article tags in that section
    for (Element artTag : allArtTags ){
        Elements atags = artTag.select("a"); //select all a tags in each article tag
        for(Element atag : atags){
            System.out.println(atag.text()); //print the link text or 
            System.out.println(atag.attr("href"));//print link
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need those nested loops and selectors. You can just do `Elements atags = doc.select("#main article a")`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in one of my projects:

```
final Elements elements = doc.select("div.item_list_section.item_description");
```

you'll have to get the elements you want to extract links from.

```
private static ... inspectElement(Element e) {
        try {
            final String name = getAttr(e, "a[href]");
            final String link = e.select("a").first().attr("href");
            //final String price = getAttr(e, "span.item_price");
            //final String category = getAttr(e, "span.item_category");
            //final String spec = getAttr(e, "span.item_specs");
            //final String datetime = e.select("time").attr("datetime");

            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
}

private static String getAttr(Element e, String what) {
    try {
        return e.select(what).first().text();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { return ""; }
}
```